# ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 4273 output values where the mask is true

Tags: arrays, numpy, corner-detection

received the following error for my code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 image = cv.imread('image.jpeg')
      2 image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
----> 3 HarrisCornerDetection(image)

Cell In[5], line 11, in HarrisCornerDetection(image)
      8 plt.subplot(1,2,1),plt.imshow(image)
      9 plt.title('Original Image')
---> 11 image[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()]=[0, 0, 255]
     12 plt.subplot(1,2,2),plt.imshow(dst_norm_scaled)
     13 plt.title('Edges')

ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 4273 output values where the mask is true
```

the code used is:

```
import glob
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def HarrisCornerDetection(image):
    image = np.float32(image)
    
    dst = cv.cornerHarris(image, 2, 3, 0.04) 
    dst = cv.dilate(dst, None)
    dst = np.float32(dst)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.subplot(1,2,1),plt.imshow(image)
    plt.title('Original Image')

    image[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()]=[0, 0, 255]
    plt.subplot(1,2,2),plt.imshow(dst_norm_scaled)
    plt.title('Corners')

image = cv.imread('image.jpeg')
image = cv.resize(image, (244, 244))
image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
HarrisCornerDetection(image)
```

I have been trying to implement Harris Corner detection using python-opencv and on running the code I received the error mentioned above.
The image used has a size of (244,244) and the length of the image array in 244.

The expected result was to get corner detected in the image. Removing *line 17* form the code; i.e., `image[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()]=[0, 0, 255]`. The output for implementing the above solution is

[image]

Comment: Examine `dst > 0.01 * dst.max()`

Comment: yes, I examined the part you asked for and changed the assigning value from an array of [0, 0, 225] to a single integer array of 225 which pointed to the corners. I am still not sure why but it was not working as per the OpenCV documentation example in my jupyter lab. I suspect the issue is with jupyter and not openCV as the imported image also showed a change in its color property.

Comment: That's a boolean mask, and so then indexing is flat.  Sounds instead like what to select pixels in a 3d array (h,w,3), and assign [0,0,255] on that last size 3 dimension.